# cannot change tabs in TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I am new to android programming and I am trying to change the tab on the touch of tab header text. Here is my code

**activity_main**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/test_image"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            />
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**Mainactivity.java**

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Output for this application is a tablayout with fragments as tabs which contain cardview. Now when I touch the tab header I am able to switch to different tabs also I can switch tab by swiping the fragments with my finger.However when I add this

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {


            CharSequence _header = tab.getText();
            Selected_Tab_Header = String.valueOf(_header);

            if (Selected_Tab_Header == "Tab1") {
                headerImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.someImage);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
```

I cannot switch tab's anymore i.e when I touch the tab header though the code is fired(image changes) the tab is not switched however swiping the tab's with finger still works.Is there any thing missing from my code? or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont forget `viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition())` in your `onTabSelected`:

```
  public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        CharSequence _header = tab.getText();
        Selected_Tab_Header = String.valueOf(_header);

        if (Selected_Tab_Header == "Tab1") {
             headerImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.someImage);
        }

        if (viewPager != null) {
             viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }
   }
```

Hope this helps!!